# how to flip an image vertically at its position using css with smooth transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to flip my image vertically (i.e. is `rotateX`) with smooth transition after few minutes at its center position. My image ois flipping but the problem is that its not fliiping on its position. Its flipping from the points somewhere above the image. I need to flip it with its center. I have tried all the rotating coordinates but its not working. Please help me

Here is my JsFiddle. you can find my codes here.

https://jsfiddle.net/bh7x7weg/

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Please show your code here rather than providing a link.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Your images origin needs to be set to `transform-origin: center center;` Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) for more information about this style.

https://jsfiddle.net/bh7x7weg/3/

Comment: I am not sure what else to suggest. It is flipping vertically from the `.image` containers central origin when I test it. I have added the jQuery include so you can see it in action without having to add the `.flipped` class in dev tools. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you want.